# Need to fetch the Contact Account name and Contact Display name from the content provider using a single cursor in Android

Tags: android

I need to list the 'Display name' of all the contacts belonging to a single account.

I am planning to use a cursor adapter for populating the list and hence would require the corresponding fields (Display name, Account info) to be fetched in a single content provider query.

Looking at the Contacts Database Structure a single table among Raw Contacts, Contacts and Data wont be able to provide these two parameters and hence a join is necessary.

As far as i know join wont be possible to fetch the data from the content provider.

Can you please let me know the solution to the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was wondering if you ever found a solution for this. I have the same problem and have yet to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may request on ContactsContract.RawContacts with a selection on your account name and then on the ContactsContract.RawContacts.data table with a selection on the mime type `CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`.

Comment: Thanks dco maeglin for you inputs. But i need to fetch all the three parameters using a single cursor which i wont be able to do for ContactsContract.RawContacts ,ContactsContract.RawContacts.data :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code (this will fill cur2 with all the name information for every contact in accounts[0].name which is just the string name of the account and it will sort it by first name):

```
 cur2 = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, DataQuery.PROJECTION, DataQuery.SELECTION, new String[] {accounts[0].name}, DataQuery.COLUMN_GIVEN_NAME + " ASC");


 private interface DataQuery {
    public static final String[] PROJECTION =
         new String[] {Data._ID, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2,
        Data.DATA3, Data.DATA4, Data.DATA5, Data.DATA6, Data.DATA7,
        Data.DATA8, Data.DATA9, Data.DATA10, Data.DATA11, Data.DATA12,
        Data.DATA13, Data.DATA14, Data.DATA15, ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME };

    public static final int COLUMN_ID = 0;
    public static final int COLUMN_MIMETYPE = 1;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA1 = 2;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA2 = 3;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA3 = 4;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA4 = 5;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA5 = 6;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA6 = 7;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA7 = 8;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA8 = 9;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA9 = 10;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA10 = 11;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA11 = 12;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA12 = 13;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA13 = 14;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA14 = 15;
    public static final int COLUMN_DATA15 = 16;
    public static final int COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER = COLUMN_DATA1;
    public static final int COLUMN_PHONE_TYPE = COLUMN_DATA2;
    public static final int COLUMN_EMAIL_ADDRESS = COLUMN_DATA1;
    public static final int COLUMN_EMAIL_TYPE = COLUMN_DATA2;
    public static final int COLUMN_GIVEN_NAME = COLUMN_DATA2;
    public static final int COLUMN_MIDDLE_NAME = COLUMN_DATA5;
    public static final int COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME = COLUMN_DATA3;
    public static final int COLUMN_WEBSITE = COLUMN_DATA1;
    public static final int COLUMN_ADDRESS_TYPE = COLUMN_DATA2;
    public static final int COLUMN_STREET_ADDRESS = COLUMN_DATA4;
    public static final int COLUMN_CITY_ADDRESS = COLUMN_DATA7;
    public static final int COLUMN_STATE_ADDRESS = COLUMN_DATA8;
    public static final int COLUMN_ZIP_ADDRESS = COLUMN_DATA9;
    public static final int COLUMN_ORGANIZATION_NAME = COLUMN_DATA1;
    public static final int COLUMN_TITLE = COLUMN_DATA4;
    public static final int COLUMN_PHOTO = COLUMN_DATA15;
    public static final int COLUMN_NOTES = COLUMN_DATA1;

    public static final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME  + "=? and "  + Data.MIMETYPE + "='vnd.android.cursor.item/name'";

    //public static final String a = Data.
}
```